# Complex critical value of real valued function with domain in $R^{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and in first derivative test, I get complex solution, should I ignore it for finding local extrema or ignore it?

Comment: please show your calculation above by clicking "Edit".

Comment: You would ignore those complex-valued critical points.

Comment: @311411 I am not a new user. And not trying to make you people solve my homework. This is a very general question and kind of verifying what I already know. Don't always "homeworkify" every question asked here.

Comment: @Clayton I thought the same. If we get a CP which are complex that doesn't make any sense for a function in R^2 since it is not defined over C^2. Just wanted to verify.

Comment: I was just curious; I didn't say anything about homework.